# Why cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, cmd) throws "the asynchronous operation has already completed"

Tags: c#, ado.net, wcf-data-services

In below code `command.EndExecuteNonQuery` throws

> the asynchronous operation has already completed.

The `EndExecuteNonQuery` ends the Async operation. MSDN states to use `EndExecuteNonQuery` to properly complete the operation. any thoughts?

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("EXEC SP", connection))
{
    AsyncCallback callback = HandleCallBack;
    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, command);
}

private void HandleCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        using (var command = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState)
        {
            command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not dispose the command (implicitly here, through the using statement) before the async operation is finished.

Replace the using statement with a try/catch to dispose the command on exceptions on Begin, and add a try/finally to dispose the command in the async callback.